# Is it permitted to stop thinking about Allah when having sex with your spouse?

Tags: sunni, nikah, allah, sex

I read somewhere that you must remember Allah (swt) when performing any action.

However you are permitted to stop thinking about Allah (swt) when having sex with your wife / husband.

Is this correct or must you think about Allah (swt) all the time?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should remember Allaah all the time. Yes, even during sex with your spouse... How? here are some examples...

1. Islam forbids entering your wife from behind (anus). Thus remember this rule when you approach her.
2. Before entering try to recite the du'a
3. Before undressing, say bismillah
4. After sex, make gusl. At least make wudu if you're going to sleep.

So yes, you remember Allaah when you remember his revealed rulings.